# Error when i compile caffe(undefined reference to `caffe::DecodeDatumNative(caffe::Datum*)')

Tags: c++, caffe

when I use commands 'sudo make all' on ubuntu14.04 I get the following error

> ```
> .build_debug/tools/compute_image_mean.o: In function `main':
> compute_image_mean.cpp:56:undefined reference to `caffe::DecodeDatumNative(caffe::Datum*)'
> ```

can anybody tell me what should I do and why this would happen?

Comment: have you configured `Makefile.config`? do you have any other errors/warnings during build? have you installed all prerequisites?

Comment: It means that at line 56, you call some functions of the `caffe` library, but at least one of these cannot be found by the linker. So either you did not install the library correctly, or you didn't tell the linker (in the makefile) where to look for it. Do you have the correct `lib` flags?

Answer (score 0):

for those searching same problem:
try delete old caffe files in `/usr/lib`,`/usr/local/lib`
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/2228
https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3396